# Excel: How to convert/format a column of text/values into a table made up by every nth line (n columns)

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, regex, conditional-formatting

I'm having to fiddle with Notepad++, Excel 'Text to Columns', regex find replace. So painful.

Must be an easier way??

Ive got:

```
heading1
heading2
heading3
value1
value2
value3
```

And I want:

| heading1 | heading2 | heading3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | value3 |

Comment: ARe there always 3 heading and 3 values? Could you show sample data?

Comment: How could we distinguish heading and value?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `SEQUENCE()` formula then this works:

[image]